# How to dynamically move from a ListView's Item Click Event to a Hard Coded Java Layout?

Tags: android, layout, android-listview

The Code below displays a dialog after clicking on a ListView's Item.I would instead like to create my own Dynamic Layout displaying the text views about the particular List Entry in the ListView. Can Someone please help?

```
package com.android.XYZ;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;


public class News_01 extends ListActivity {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Vector<RowData> data;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        data = new Vector<RowData>();
        RowData rd; 
        rd = new RowData("Detailed Report 1", "Story 1");
        data.add(rd);
        rd = new RowData("Detailed Report 2", "Story 2");
        data.add(rd);
        rd = new RowData("Detailed Report 3", "Story 3");
        data.add(rd);
        rd = new RowData("Detailed Report 4", "Story 4");
        data.add(rd);
        rd = new RowData("Detailed Report 5", "Story 5");
        data.add(rd);
        rd = new RowData("Detailed Report 6", "Story 6");
        data.add(rd);
        rd = new RowData("Detailed Report 7", "Story 7");
        data.add(rd);
        rd = new RowData("Detailed Report 8", "Story 8");
        data.add(rd);
        rd = new RowData("Detailed Report 9", "Story 9");
        data.add(rd);
        rd = new RowData("Detailed Report 10", "Story 10");
        data.add(rd);

        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.news_01,R.id.text_1, data);
        setListAdapter(adapter);        
        getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);       
    }


    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        CustomAdapter adapter = (CustomAdapter) parent.getAdapter();
            RowData row = adapter.getItem(position);
```

New Code --> (This is what i want to display after someone clicks on any item on the ListView)
                ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);

```
            sv.setBackgroundColor(Integer.parseInt("d3d3d3", 16));

            LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);

            ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

            sv.addView(ll);

            TextView tv = new TextView(this);

            tv.setText(row.mTitle);

            ll.addView(sv);
```

I want to add the hard coded dynamic layout whenever we click
a list view's Item?

Original Code--->

```
        Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setTitle(row.mDescription); 

        builder.setMessage(row.mTitle + " -> " + position );

        builder.setPositiveButton("ok", null);

        builder.show();

        }

    /**
     * Data type used for custom adapter. Single item of the adapter.      
     */
    private class RowData {
        protected String mTitle;
            protected String mDescription;

            RowData(String title, String description){
                mTitle = title;
                mDescription = description;                                  
        }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                    return mTitle + " " +  mDescription;
            }
    }

    private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowData> {

            public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource,
                            int textViewResourceId, List<RowData> objects) {
                    super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);

            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    ViewHolder holder = null;

                    //widgets displayed by each item in your list
                    TextView item = null;
                    TextView description = null;

                    //data from your adapter
                    RowData rowData= getItem(position);


                    //we want to reuse already constructed row views...
                    if(null == convertView){
                            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.news_01, null);
                            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
                            convertView.setTag(holder);
                    }
                    // 
                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                    item = holder.getItem();
                    item.setText(rowData.mTitle);

                    description = holder.getDescription();          
                    description.setText(rowData.mDescription);

                    return convertView;
            }
    }

    /**
     * Wrapper for row data.
     *
     */
    private class ViewHolder {      
        private View mRow;
        private TextView description = null;
        private TextView item = null;

            public ViewHolder(View row) {
            mRow = row;
            }

            public TextView getDescription() {
                    if(null == description){
                            description = (TextView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.text_1);
                    }
                    return description;
            }

            public TextView getItem() {
                    if(null == item){
                            item = (TextView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.text_1);
                    }
                    return item;
            }       
    }}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6YIO.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vC65C.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want a custom dialog.  Try [this](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application)

Comment: I would like to create a dynamic layout i already have a code to create a dialog above.I would want to create a layout which would be activated from the onListItemClick() method of the ListView.How to do that?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry.  I'm missing something.  With a custom dialog, you can use any layout you like in the dialog.  If you need to customise the layout at runtime, then inflate the layout, get references to the controls on it in the normal way and make changes.  You seem to be using an alert dialog which you cannot customise.  My suggestion is to use a custom dialog which is fully definable.

Comment: I'm also curious, why this sv.setBackgroundColor(Integer.parseInt("d3d3d3", 16))

Comment: Yes. You are right!sv.setBackgroundColor(Integer.parseInt("d3d3d3", 16)) was used to update the background color which i was using.....i guess i was unsuccessful with that attempt. Any way i'm posting the corrected version of the code:

Comment: @Override
 public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
     CustomAdapter adapter = (CustomAdapter) parent.getAdapter();
         RowData row = adapter.getItem(position);
         String t = row.mTitle;
         String b = row.mDescription;

      
         AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
         LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_01story,null);

Comment: TextView textView1 = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.story_body);
         textView1.setText(t);
         TextView textView2 = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.story_title);
         textView2.setText(b);      
         builder.setView(layout);
         builder.show();
 }

Comment: I beg you pardon for the poor indentation in the code above.ne ways this code works well!